# Google Maps Blank Screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I recently opened a new project with Android Studio and attempted to use the default Map Activity to generate a map on my app. However, when I run the app on my test device, there is simply a blank screen with a google logo in the bottom corner. I have already made an API key, and inserted in both google_maps_api.xml files, as well as used both an emulator with an x86 system image as well as a real test device.

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.subhendugoswami.spaces" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission       android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.subhendugoswami.frontend.testLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.subhendugoswami.frontend.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    android:debuggable="true"
</application>
```

MapsActivity.java
    package com.example.subhendugoswami.frontend;

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.subhendugoswami.spaces.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get api key (For more information use [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)).
Then for debugging mode you have to copy your api key into 'app\src\debug\res\values\google_maps_api.xml' and for release mode copy it into 'app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml'.

Comment: I am not seeing the app\src\debug or app\src\release directories in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I simply created a new directory, new key, and a new project and for project compiled and ran fine